# Code highlighting is not working on OllyDbg

Tags: debugging, assembly, ollydbg

I am a new user of OllyDbg and I cannot find a way to highlight the ASM code. I have checked the settings and it looks like the configuration is correct. Also, I have tried two versions of OllyDbg (1.1, 2.0).

Comment: Apropos the close vote: Questions pertaining to **software tools commonly used by programmers** are on topic.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Use `Options -> Appearance -> Code highlighting` to define highlighting schemes, and right click the window you want to apply the settings to and `Appearance -> Highlighting` to apply it (2.01 beta 2).

Comment: I have tried it but it doesn't work. I have selected several schemes and the color of the code doesn't change.

Comment: Provide more information on what doesn't work, screenshots perhaps.

Comment: Sorry, you are right. I had to press the right button of the mouse on the code and select Appearance -> Highlighting. Thanks a lot!